# Derby Overflow in a select query

Tags: java, overflow, derby

I am writing a query to select values in my Derby database:

```
select   ol_number,
     sum(ol_quantity) as sum_qty,
     sum(ol_amount) as sum_amount,
     avg(ol_quantity) as avg_qty,
     avg(ol_amount) as avg_amount,
     count(*) as count_order
```

The data type of ol_number, ol_amount and ol_quantity is integer. But their maximum value is
2147483647.

But it throws a SqlException which SQLState is 22003.

The exception is:
`java.sql.SQLDataException: Overflow occurred during numeric data type conversion of "1500000"`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Client driver? The only place where I see that error being thrown is when Derby fails to convert a BigDecimal into the representation used in the DRDA protocol. If this is reproducible as simple sql I think it should be
[logged as a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa)

Comment: Yes, I am using derbyclient-10.8.1.2.jar.

So, maybe it be an internal error?